# VBA is disabled in Excel Home and Student 2010 (on XP SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

Everything seems to be working fine with Office, except that in Excel the VBA/Macro functionality is disabled. I cannot launch the editor, all macro-enabled files are interpreted as corrupt and the 'unreadable content' (i.e. the VBA code) gets discarded before they open. The weird thing is the "Record Macro" button is enabled but when I click ok to name the macro first I get an error message saying there is something wrong with the name (format, character or name taken etc.)

I went in the disc through the installation menu I tried to re-install VBA (or repair) and the process goes through fine, no errors. In fact I'm certain it was already installed fine in the first place. Perhaps something wrong with the XP OS?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the VBE and macro recorder disabled if you open up Excel without opening a workbook?

Comment: Yes indeed. The buttons are there but faded out. The record macro button works but the process fails as soon as I click OK to name my Macro as I explained above

Comment: Well, Win XP has been officially out of official support for quite a while now, best of luck!